# MVC, Java Куда положить файлы с инструкциями и как сделать ссылки на них

Tags: java, файлы, mvc, jsp

Имеется набор pdf-файлов с инструкциями на разных языках и кнопка на Jsp-странице. Надо навесить на эту кнопку показ этих файлов в браузере или скачивание для соответственного языка. Скачивание желательно сделать силами браузера. То есть обычная процедура: идешь по ссылке и либо открывается, либо спрашивает стандартно открыть или сохранить. Куда мне положить файлы в проекте и как задать ссылки на них?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот описание структуры вэб модуля
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html

Все статические файлы можно положить в корневую папку с вэб контентом.
Если папка корневая папка называется webapp  и Вы свои статические файлы положите webapp/instructions/myfile.pdf, то ссылка будет выглядеть так:

href=[web контекст приложения]/instructions/myfile.pdf

Comment: Спасибо, работает